# How to blur Landsat 8 image using a gaussian smooth filter with specified sigma value before downloading using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, export, landsat-8, smoothing

I would like to add gaussian blur with sigma = 'some value' to Landsat 8 images before I download them using `Google Earth Engine` (GEE). So far I managed to simple download the images without adding the gaussian blur. Can some1 help me? Here is my code for download the PAN band from Landsat 8.

```
//Load Landsat 8 TOA reflectance dataset
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")

//Create mask function
function maskL8(image) {
  // Bit 4 is cloud.
  var cloudBitMask = (1 << 4);

  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('BQA');

  // Flag should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

//Filter L8 TOA dataset to country polygon boundaries,
//month and year.
//Apply masking function to L8 TOA dataset
var landsat = landsat
.filterBounds(table)
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(11,11,'month'))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2013,2013,'year'))
.map(maskL8)
.select('B8','BQA')

//Map.addLayer(landsat.select('B8'))
Map.centerObject(landsat)

//Calculate median value for the filter and masked dataset
var median = landsat
.select('B8')
.reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
.clip(table);
Map.addLayer(median)
print(median)

//Export image to Drive storage
Export.image.toDrive({image:median,
scale:15,
region:table,
maxPixels:1e12,
description:'pan',
crs: 'EPSG:7767'
})
```

I know how to do it in `R` but I would like to do do it in `GEE` as well. For example in `R` it is very straightforward, e.g.,:

```
library(raster)
library(spatialEco)

pan = raster ("path/pan.tif")
smoothed = spatialEco::raster.gaussian.smooth(pan, sigma = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GEE it is also pretty straightforward. I think you are looking for `convolve` to perform a convolution on your image and `ee.Kernel.gaussian` to define the gaussian filter.

```
// Define parameters of the kernel
var kernel = ee.Kernel.gaussian({
  radius: 3,
  sigma: 0.5, 
  units: 'pixels'
});

// Convolve image with kernel
median = median.convolve(kernel);
```

Comment: Why you set the radius: 3 and not some other value like 5 or 7 for example? What I mean is based on what criteria did you chose this value?

Comment: It was a totally arbitrary decision. You can set any number in the radius parameter. You just need to consider that this radius will determine the size of the filter; thus, in this case, for each focal pixel it will calculate the gaussian filter for all the pixels that are in a distance of a 3-pixel radius.